# State Monad with multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, scala, monads, state-monad

Let's say I have a stateful client smth like

```
trait Client {
  case class S(connection: Connection, failures: Int) // Connection takes 10 seconds to create
  def fetchData: State[S, Data] // Takes 10 seconds to fetch
}
```

I want to make it stateful because the creation of connection is expensive (so I want to cache it) + I have failures count to signal if there are too many failures in a row, then basically recreate connection.

What I've understood from State monad is that effectively it should be calculated on one thread, chaining immutable states sequentially on that thread. I can't afford it in this case, because I fetch operation takes huge amount of time, while all I need is quickly read the state, use the connection from there to start expensive async call. On the other hand, I can't make it `State[S, Task[Data]]`, bacause I need to modify `failures` in `S` if the task `fetchData` fails. So I modified client to be

```
import fs2.Task

trait Client {
  case class S(connection: Connection, failures: Int) // Connection takes 10 seconds to create
  def fetchData: StateT[Task, S, Data] // Takes 10 seconds to fetch
}
```

The thing is I can come up with some Monoid that can add the states irrelevant if what was the initial state. E.g. If I have `S1 -> (S2, Data)`, `S1 -> (S3, Data)`, I could still add S2 and S3 to arrive at the final state regardless of what came before - S2 or S3.

Now I have a kind of Java server (Thrift) that use the handler. I haven't dig into details of how it working precisely yet, but let's assume that it listens for incoming connections and then spawns a thread on which it handles the data retrieval. So in my case I want to block the thread until `Task` is finished:

```
 class Server(client: Client) {
    def handle: Data {
       run(client.fetchData)
    }

    private var state: S = Monoid[S].mempty

    private def run(st: State[S, Data]): Data {
      val resTask: Task[(S, Data)] = st.run(state)
      val (newState, res) = Await.result(resTask.unsafeRunAsyncFuture)
      state.synchonized({
        state = Monoid[S].mappend(state, newState)
      })
      res
    }
 }
```

My questions are:

1) Am I doing it the right / best way here (my focus is efficiency / no bugs)

2) Do I really need State monad here, or it's better to use ordinary var and work with it?

3) In the examples of State monad I always saw that state is propagated to the top level of the app and handled there. But maybe it's better to handle it on `Client` level and expose stateless interface to the app?

4) Is this code thread safe, or I should make state some sort of synchronized var? I know that in Objective C this line `state = Monoid[S].mappend(state, newState)` could crash if in the middle of assignment the state was read from another thread.